# query to retrieve object from has_many through association

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have 3 models:

```
Product
has_many :variants, dependent: :destroy
has_many :stocks,   through: :variants

Stock
belongs_to :variant

Variant 
has_many :stocks, dependent: :destroy
belongs_to :product
```

In my stocks index I need to filter by product's `:title`

This is my attempt

```
@stocks = Stock.joins(:variant)
  .joins("INNER JOIN 'products' ON 'variants'.'id' =\'variants'.'product_id'")
  .where('lower(variants.product.title) LIKE ?', "%#{params[:query][:keyword].downcase }%")
```

I have this error but I don't get what is wrong

> PG::SyntaxError: ERROR:  syntax error at or near "'products'"
>   LINE 1: ...variants"."id" = "stocks"."variant_id" INNER JOIN 'products'...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can join product with AR syntax

```
@stocks = Stock.joins(variant: :product)
  .where('lower(products.title) LIKE ?', "%#{params[:query][:keyword].downcase }%")
```

Comment: Happy to help you :) Please, [accept](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) the answer if it helped